# Swagger client generator - Conflict with Response.class

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

I'm creating a rest client with io.swagger generator and a given yaml file, the yaml defines a Response element that result in a Response.class creates by the generator. The problem is that in another generated DefaultApi class the imports includes this class and a javax.ws.rs.core.Response that is not used but generete a conflict between both imports. If I rename the Response element in the yaml file, the problem disappears but in reality I shudn't change this file.
Is there a way to indicate to the generator to create the class with another name (alias)? I'm traing not to change de yaml file.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

...

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                    <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                    <!-- <language>java</language> -->
                    <language>jaxrs-cxf-client</language>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>src/main/resources/technicalViability.yaml</inputSpec>
<!--                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiCallback.java,ApiClient.java,ApiException.java,ApiResponse.java,Configuration.java,Pair.java,ProgressRequestBody.java,ProgressResponseBody.java,StringUtil.java,ApiKeyAuth.java,Authentication.java,HttpBasicAuth.java,JSON.java,OAuth.java</supportingFilesToGenerate> -->
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

...

```
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>${swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.version}</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generate</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

technicalViability.yml

```
paths:
 /technicalViability:
   get:
     produces:
        - application/xml
        - application/json
     parameters:
     - name: "tlkServiceId"
       in: "query"
       description: "Servicio TLK"
       required: false
       type: "string"
     - name: "tincoServiceId"
       in: "query"
       description: "Servicio Tinco"
       required: false
       type: "string"

     responses:
       "200":
         description: "OK"
         schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/response"
     security:
      - sso_auth: []

securityDefinitions:
  sso_auth:
    type: "oauth2"
    flow: accessCode
    authorizationUrl: "--"
    tokenUrl: "--"

definitions:
  response:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      code:
        type: "integer"
        description: "codigo de respuesta"
      message:
        type: "string"
        description: "mensaje descriptivo"
      listaFacilidades:
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/facilidad"
  facilidad:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      wp_cod_sefp:
        type: "string"
        description: "codigo psef"
      wp_tipo_sefp:
        type: "string"
        description: "tipo de psef"
```

DefaultApi.class

```
package io.swagger.api;

import io.swagger.model.Response;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.*;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.PATCH;

/**
 * Technical Viability
 *
 * <p>No description provided (generated by Swagger Codegen https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)
 *
 */
@Path("/")
@Api(value = "/", description = "")
public interface DefaultApi  {

    @GET
    @Path("/technicalViability")
    @Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    @ApiOperation(value = "", tags={  })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = Response.class) })
    public Response technicalViabilityGet(@QueryParam("tlkServiceId")String tlkServiceId, @QueryParam("tincoServiceId")String tincoServiceId);
}
```

**Error**: The import javax.ws.rs.core.Response collides with another import statement

Answer (score 0):

For such cases you should pick one to use in the `imports` and the other's fully qualified class name(package name + class name) to specify where you want to put it. Or else you will face **The import xxxx.Response collides with another import statement**. So, for instance remove  `io.swagger.model.Response` from imports, then:

```
public  io.swagger.model.Response technicalViabilityGet(@QueryParam("tlkServiceId")String tlkServiceId, @QueryParam("tincoServiceId")String tincoServiceId);
```

Comment: The problem is that that implies change a generated class, which means that every time I run a maven install it will overwrithe the modification.

Comment: You don't have to change any thing, this is a know issue when you have conflicting `imports`. **Note**, If all the classes are generated automatically you are right there is only a possibility of changing your models.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I changed the way of generate the client and the problem is gone.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.5.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
...
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger-codegen-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                    <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                    <language>java</language>
                </configuration>
```